Jupyter Notebook Cell Run Count Going Up in 2s
My jupyter notebook cell count is starting at 2 and going up in 2s. I.e. the first cell I run (even after I restart the Kernel) has a cell count 2, the next is 4, then 6 etc (see screenshot).Does anyone know how I can fix this and make it so the cell count starts at 1 and goes up in 1s like it should?

Have any of those cells been executed? That should update the cell numbers

@inspectorG4dget Yes, they have all been executed after restarting the kernal. I have no idea why it is doing it.

There was an issue with a version of an extension recently where it was messing up numbering of cells in Jupyter, see this post 'Cell numbering broken on new Jupyter lab/notebook' here a the Jupyter Discourse forum. Is that maybe what you are experiencing? The issue seemed to be an extension Anaconda was including. (I suspect this post on SO yesterday may also be related.)

@Wayne Thanks so much for sharing these links. I found in the first one that it is to do with the anaconda assistant. Disabling it using this ('jupyter labextension disable @anaconda/assistant') and then restarting Jupyter notebook fixed it. Thanks again

As @Wayne suggested, the problem it is to do with the Anaconda Assistant. Steps to fix:

Disable Anaconda Assistant
Run jupyter labextension disable @anaconda/assistant
Restart the Jupyter notebook

